# Order of middleware parsing with body-parser

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, body-parser

Alright so I am trying to understand Node.js and Typescript, so I tried working on a simple script which is as follows;

1. app.ts

```js
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { Routes } from "./routes/crm_routes";

class App {
    public app;
    public routePrv : Routes = new Routes();

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.routePrv.routes(this.app);
        this.config();
    }
    private config():void  {
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json);
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    }
}

export default new App().app;
```

2. ./lib/routes/crm_routes.ts

```js
import {Request, Response} from "express";

export class Routes {       
    public routes(app): void {          
        app.route('/').get((req, res) => res.json({name : "ohmygodnotthisagain"}));
    }
}
```

3. server.ts

```js
import app from "./app";
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Now I was playing around so I put this.config() above this.routePrv.routes(this.app), and my server stopped routing to / altogether.
When I put them back in the above order it started working again.

Now I tried to understand the cause of this, and am confused, is it because body-parser needs to be the last middleware called such that auth, extra checks, etc middleware complete working or are there something else?

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks!
PS: I'm pretty new to TS, pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Body parser (or the middleware in general) should be called before the actual route.

Your route is not working because you have a spelling error here:

```
this.app.use(bodyParser.json);
```

Should be:

```
this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The route works when you put that code last, because its never actually executed (the route gets matched first and stops the execution, since you are not calling the `next()` function)